# CakePHP, setting a value in controller is not available in .ctp file

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to set a variable in my controller so that I can reference it in a view file

Here is an example of a successful set statement from the same action/function

```
//users_controller.php, index() function
$this->set('bidBalance', $this->Membership->User->Point->balance($this->Auth->user('id'), true));
```

With the above, in my index.ctp file I can display the result by:

```
print($bidBalance);
```

So I have to get some other data back to the view so I do the following:

```
$this->set('nextMembership', 
    $this->Membership->find('first', array('conditions' => 
        array('Membership.rank >' => $membership['Membership']['rank']), 
        'contain' => '', 'order' => array('Membership.rank' => 'asc'))));
```

And when I try to access $nextMembership in my view file I get a notice:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: nextMembership [APP/views/themed/users/index.ctp, line 138
```

The thing is the query I assign to 'nextMembership' is used elsewhere and successfully returns data so I am not sure what is wrong.

Also, for my sanity's sake I even tried

```
$this->set('nextMembership', 'hello world');
```

But I still get the undefined notice.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to put your call result into a variable and debug the variable. Then use set on the variable not on the complete call.
$nextMembership = $this->Membership->find('first', array('conditions' => 
        array('Membership.rank >' => $membership['Membership']['rank']), 
        'contain' => '', 'order' => array('Membership.rank' => 'asc')));
debug($nextMembership);
$this->set('nextMembership', $nextMembership);
What does the debug output say?

Comment: Same outcome. And my last code line of set('nextMembership', 'hello world'); causes the notice too so there is something else going on

Comment: What does the debug($nextMembership); say inside the controller? Before you use "set".

Comment: I am new to Cake, I added that line after the assign, before the set, but nothing showed when I refreshed my view

Comment: Have you set your debugging level to 2? Look in the core.php.
You should see at least an empty debug output.

Comment: What so after I change users_controller.php I need to view core.php?

Answer (score 2):

First of all,if you are in a development mode,I recommends you to change the cakephp debug mode to level 2. You can do it on core.php file located in Config folder by changing `Configure::write('debug', 0);` to `Configure::write('debug', 2);` .After the changing, you can use debug($nextMembership) instead of print().It will give you better debugging results.

To confirms you query is correct,try to seperate the code like this format:

```
$nextMemberships =  $this->Membership->find('first', array(
                     'conditions' => 
                     array('Membership.rank >' => $membership['Membership']['rank']), 
                   'contain' => '', 
                   'order' => array('Membership.rank' => 'asc')));
$this->set(compact('nextMemberships'));
```

And in your View ,

place this at the top of the file : `debug($nextMemberships)` .

Hope this help.

Comment: I would even put the debug in the controller, too. So andrewb can see if the variable is filled correctly in the controller and then check if it is transferred correctly into the view.